# Block validation - conflict between my attrributes and save.js file

Tags: block-editor

Within my block plugin, I have an attribute file (index.js), and within it I have a **mediaLinks** attribute where and I am trying to use default values along with a query process...

`My index.js file`

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import Edit from './edit';
import Save from './save';

registerBlockType( 'mediagallery/item', {
    title: __( 'Media Gallery Block Item', 'mg-block-item' ),
    description: __(
        'A sub block associated to the Media Gallery parent block',
        'mg-block'
    ),
    category: 'text',
    icon: {
        src: 'controls-play',
        foreground: '#6a5acd',
    },
    parent: [ 'mg-block/mediagallery' ],
    supports: {
        reusable: false,
        html: false,
    },
    attributes: {
        mediaLinks: {
            type: 'array',
            source: 'query',
            selector: '.wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links ul li',
            default: [
                {
                    link: 'https://video-one',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
                {
                    link: 'https://video-two',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
                {
                    link: 'https://video-three',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
            ],
            query: {
                icon: {
                    source: 'attribute',
                    attribute: 'data-icon',
                },
                link: {
                    source: 'attribute',
                    selector: 'a',
                    attribute: 'href',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    edit: Edit,
    save: Save,
} );
```

...But even though the above works initially, when I refresh my edit page, WordPress does not see a match between post and save, and throws the following error...

```
Content generated by `save` function:

<div class="wp-block-mediagallery-item"><button class="vid-img"><img src="http://wp.gblocks:63630/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/AGExplorer-VG-cover-ChrisDanner_382x191.webp" alt="" class="wp-image-409"/></button><h2 class="vid-name">Joe Right</h2><div class="vid-title"><p>Web Dev</p></div><div class="vid-content"><p>Works out of Paris</p></div><div class="wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links"><ul><li><a href="https://video-one"></a></li><li><a href="https://video-two"></a></li><li><a href="https://video-three"></a></li></ul></div></div>


Content retrieved from post body:

<div class="wp-block-mediagallery-item"><button class="vid-img"><img src="http://wp.gblocks:63630/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/AGExplorer-VG-cover-ChrisDanner_382x191.webp" alt="" class="wp-image-409"/></button><h2 class="vid-name">Joe Right</h2><div class="vid-title"><p>Web Dev</p></div><div class="vid-content"><p>Works out of Paris</p></div><div class="wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links"><ul><li><a href="https://video-one"><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-media-video"></span></a></li><li><a href="https://video-two" data-icon="media-video"><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-media-video"></span></a></li><li><a href="https://video-three" data-icon="media-video"><span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-media-video"></span></a></li></ul></div></div>
```

Notice in the above error statement, the **save** is not seeing `<span class="dashicon dashicons dashicons-media-video"></span>` and its not seeing `data-icon="media-video"`

Why would that be?

`my save.js file`

```
import { useBlockProps} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Icon } from '@wordpress/components';

export default function Save( { attributes } ) {
    const { mediaLinks } = attributes;
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save({});

    return (
        <div { ...blockProps }>

          /* ...other stuff here like name, title, and content... */
    
            { mediaLinks.length > 0 && (
                <div className="wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links">
                    <ul>
                        { mediaLinks.map( ( item, index ) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={ index }>
                                    <a
                                        href={ item.link }
                                        data-icon={ item.icon }
                                    >
                                        <Icon icon={ item.icon } />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            );
                        } ) }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ) }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Thanks for any tips on how to use the icon component, and default attributes correctly for saving purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a good learning experience. The icon component and defaults are working just fine. My issue in this specific case is getting a grip on my source query within `index.js`, and making sure my `save.js` file represents its structure.

Within my `save.js` file, I had `data-icon={ item.icon }` on the anchor element. But in my `index.js` file, I was telling that same query icon attribute to instead be on the `li` selector. The core of my issue.

Visually speaking, the following structure now helps me understand that I want my data-icon to live on my `li` element :

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import Edit from './edit';
import Save from './save';

registerBlockType( 'mediagallery/item', {
    title: __( 'Media Gallery Block Item', 'mg-block-item' ),
    description: __(
        'A sub block associated to the Media Gallery parent block',
        'mg-block'
    ),
    category: 'text',
    icon: {
        src: 'controls-play',
        foreground: '#6a5acd',
    },
    parent: [ 'mg-block/mediagallery' ],
    supports: {
        reusable: false,
        html: false,
    },
    attributes: {
        mediaLinks: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [
                {
                    link: 'https://video-one',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
                {
                    link: 'https://video-two',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
                {
                    link: 'https://video-three',
                    icon: 'media-video',
                },
            ],
            source: 'query',
            selector: '.wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links ul li',
            query: {
                icon: {
                    source: 'attribute',
                    attribute: 'data-icon',
                },
                link: {
                    source: 'attribute',
                    selector: 'a',
                    attribute: 'href',
                },
            },
        },
    },
    edit: Edit,
    save: Save,
} );
```

And! I want that same structure reflected in my save.js file...

```
            { mediaLinks.length > 0 && (
                <div className="wp-block-mediagallery-item-media-links">
                    <ul>
                        { mediaLinks.map( ( item, index ) => {
                            return (
                                <li key={ index } data-icon={ item.icon }>
                                    <a href={ item.link }>
                                        <Icon icon={ item.icon } />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            );
                        } ) }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            ) }
```

As a result the error is gone, and both post and save have a clean match.